# How can you create a local server using Swagger specification, usable for testing clients?

Tags: c++, qt, swagger

We're in the process of setting up a web service and clients using Swagger to define the interface.  Our client is a c++ app, and we're using the C++/Qt5 code generator provided by Swagger to create our interface classes.

I'd like to create a unit test framework that will let us test these interface classes, but to do so, I'd like to have a local app that is running the server end of the protocol such that we can connect as locally.

I tried running the "Generate Server" feature on the swagger editor (http://editor.swagger.io/#/) to produce different servers, but the only one I could get to work was the node.js one, which doesn't appear to be a server that fulfills the defined protocol, but instead a documentation server that allows you to use web forms to send messages to another server.

I don't need anything fancy - just a local process I can send HTTP to that will send back canned responses in order to close the connectivity loop.  I know little-to-nothing about web application development, and the team that is responsible for implementing our actual server has bigger fish to fry right now than to write a testing app for me.